# Match string with a multi-character limit

Tags: regex

I need to divide a list in alphabetical order.

I am using:

```
regexp_match("via",'^[A-G]')
```

for one segment, and

```
regexp_match("via",'^[H-Z]')
```

However, I need to cut the list halfway the "G" set of words, that is: to make "Galveston" fall in the first segment, and "Geneve" in the second.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please give some example of your list entries.

Comment: 1) `^([A-F]|G[a-d])` and 2) `^([H-Z]|G[e-z])`

Comment: If my answer lacks something please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two regexps:

```sql
^([A-F]|G[a-d])
^([H-Z]|G[e-z])
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/s3itpu/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/s3itpu/2).

*Details*

- `^([A-F]|G[a-d])` - a letter from `A` to `F`, or `G` followed with a letter from `a` to `d`
- `^([H-Z]|G[e-z])` - a letter from `H` to `Z`, or `G` followed with a letter from `e` to `z`.

Comment: Thank you. Works great.